# Atom data-grammar syntax for keybindings

Tags: atom-editor

Can someone give a full explanation of the syntax for Atom's data-grammar attribute (used in keybinding selectors)?

For instance, what is the difference between

```
[data-grammar='source example']
```

and

```
[data-grammar~='source example']
```

?

Also, how do you specify multiple grammars? For instance, how would you specify that a key binding should be limited to html or xml formats?

If there already exists documentation on this somewhere, I have not yet found it, but would appreciate being pointed to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Quick Example:

**keymap.cson**:

```
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='text tex latex']":
  'f5':'latex:build'
```

## Grammar Information & Documentation

I began by looking at the [`file-types`](https://atom.io/packages/file-types) package. `source` and `text` categorize languages - `source` deals with development languages, while `text` deals with documentation/logs formats. 
You can add and customize language recognition by reading the flight manual. I've linked some specific sections below that are helpful for that.

> Flight Manual | Basic Customization:
>
> > [Language Recognition](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition)
> >
> > [Language Specific Settings](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#language-specific-settings-in-your-config-file)

### Working with `[data-grammar]`:

The little doocumentation given is listed under the Keymaps in Depth section.

> Flight Manual | Keymaps in Depth
>
> > [Selectors and Custom Packages](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#selectors-and-custom-packages).

This also describes the `not([...])` functionality used below and how to manipulate various rules.

Although in the above, grammars are listed in a dot format, ie `source.c`, to use them in the `[data-grammar='<name>']` format spaces are instead required.

An example of how I might use the data grammar option in my keymap.cson config is as such (here I'm using the latex package):

```
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='text tex latex']":
  'f5':'latex:build'
```

The `~` is not the correct syntax for desired functionality with data-grammar. Instead, use something like `"atom-text-editor:not([data-grammar='<name>'])":`

Note that you wouldn't use `data-grammar` in something like `config.cson`. The syntax for language specifics looks something like this instead:

```
# **config.cson**
".latex.tex.text":
  editor:
    softWrap: true
```

### **Extra useful information - List of registered Grammars**

A dump of the output of `Object.keys(atom.grammars.grammarsByScopeName).sort().join('\n')` through the Dev Console (View > Developer > Toggle Developer Options > Console)

```
source.c
source.cake
source.clojure
source.coffee
source.cpp
source.cs
source.css
source.css.less
source.css.scss
source.csx
source.diff
source.gfm
source.git-config
source.go
source.gotemplate
source.java
source.java-properties
source.js
source.js.rails source.js.jquery
source.js.regexp
source.js.regexp.replacement
source.json
source.litcoffee
source.makefile
source.nant-build
source.objc
source.objcpp
source.perl
source.perl6
source.plist
source.python
source.python.django
source.regexp.python
source.ruby
source.ruby.gemfile
source.ruby.rails
source.ruby.rails.rjs
source.sass
source.shell
source.sql
source.sql.mustache
source.sql.ruby
source.strings
source.toml
source.verilog
source.yaml
text.bibtex
text.git-commit
text.git-rebase
text.html.basic
text.html.erb
text.html.gohtml
text.html.jsp
text.html.mustache
text.html.php
text.html.ruby
text.hyperlink
text.junit-test-report
text.log.latex
text.plain
text.plain.null-grammar
text.python.console
text.python.traceback
text.shell-session
text.tex
text.tex.latex
text.tex.latex.beamer
text.tex.latex.memoir
text.todo
text.xml
text.xml.plist
text.xml.xsl
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mr G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589004/3217306), `atom-text-editor[data-grammar~='html']` with the `~=` means match an `<atom-text-editor>` HTML element with a `data-grammar` attribute that contains "html" amongst any other possible whitespace separated words.

For example, if the current language of the file is PHP, then the text-editor HTML element will look something like this:

```
<atom-text-editor data-grammar="text html php">
```

And `atom-text-editor[data-grammar~='html']` will match this.

More info on attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

As for trying to select multiple grammars, I don't think it's possible unless they share a common word in the `data-grammar` attribute, e.g., both HTML and PHP share "html", or both C and JavaScript share "source" (but in this case many other grammars share "source"). The only other way is to specify a keymap for each grammar individually even if it's the same key combination.