# Key binding by file type

Tags: atom-editor

#### Description

I'm trying to create a key binding that behaves differently based on the file type.
Ideally what id like to do is the following:

If the file type is *.md* then run the command `markdown-preview-plus:toggle`
else run the command `script:run`

I know it's something along the lines of:

file init.coffee :

```
editor.command('custom:command', e => {
  if ( of file type .md) {
    markdown-preview-plus:toggle
  } else {
    script:run
  }
})
```

Then in the keymap.cson i have to add something like:

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'cmd-i': 'custom:command'
```

But obviously this is pseudocode. I've tried reading the documentation specifically [this](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#overloading-key-bindings)
but there isn't enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding the following to the keymap.cson file:

```
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar='source gfm']":
 'cmd-i': 'markdown-preview-plus:toggle'

"atom-text-editor:not([data-grammar='source gfm'])":
   'cmd-i': 'script:run'
```

For anyone trying to do something similar to this, I used this as reference:
[Atom grammer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008745/atom-data-grammar-syntax-for-keybindings)